# distance function on Riemannian manifold $F(x) := dist(x,x^0)$ is geodesic convex?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, convex-optimization, smooth-manifolds, geodesic

Assume that $\mathcal{M}$ is a smooth riemannian manifold, define $F(x) := dist(x,x^0)$, where $F:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then is it $F$ geodesic convex?

Answer (score 7):

Not necessarily. For example, let $M$ be the unit sphere with its round metric, let $x^0$ be the north pole, and let $x$ and $y$ be two points whose distance from $x^0$ is equal to some constant $r>\pi/2$. If $\gamma:[0,1]\to M$ is a minimizing geodesic from $x$ to $y$, then the distance from $x^0$ to $\gamma(t)$ achieves a strict *maximum* at $\gamma(1/2)$, which can't happen for a geodesically convex function.

If $M$ is a Cartan-Hadamard manifold (a complete, simply connected Riemannian manifold with nonpositive sectional curvature), then $F$ is geodesically convex. See, for example, Lemma 12.15 in my *Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds*, 2nd ed., which proves that the squared distance function is strictly geodesically convex. That proof can easily be adapted to show that $F$ is (weakly) geodesically convex.

Comment: Do you mean nonpositive curvature?

Comment: @Max: Oops, right. Now fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I think that the question was about the distance function, and not the squared distance function. What about the latter?

Comment: @TrivialPursuit: That's true, but as I said in my answer, the proof of Lemma 12.15 can easily be adapted to show that the distance function itself is weakly geodesically convex.

Comment: @JackLee: Is that possible to choose two points whose distance from $x^0$ is equal to some constant $r>\pi /2$? I think all points on sphere have distance $r\leq \pi /2$.

Comment: @C.F.G: Yes, it's always possible. The maximum distance between points on the unit sphere is $\pi$.

Comment: Ah, I thought it is $\pi/2$!

Comment: @JackLee: Can we replace the simply-connectivity assumption by connectivity here?

Comment: @TianLAN: No. For example, on a flat torus, the distance from any point has saddle points. For a noncompact example, you can take a flat cylinder, which has the same property. If you want an example with strictly negative curvature, consider a hyperboloid of one sheet in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @JackLee: Okay, thanks! Btw, in these cases, it holds locally, right? (Say, for a fixed p, and the geodesic is close enough to p)

Comment: @TianLAN: Yes, that's true. You can prove it by adapting my proof of Lemma 12.15 by using the Hessian comparison theorem with a local upper bound on curvature; or you can adapt the argument of Problem 6-5 for proving the existence of geodesically convex neighborhoods.